# Kodein - retrieve ViewModel fragment parent

Tags: android, kodein

I'm working on Android, but I guess the concept would be the same on every platforms.

I have a fragment A hosting another fragment B using a NavHostFragment.

I can retrieve the ViewModel from fragment A easily :

```
class FragmentA : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    protected val parentKodein by closestKodein()
    override val kodeinContext = kcontext<Fragment>(this)

    override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        extend(parentKodein)
        import(myViewModelModule)
    }

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by instance()
}
```

The module is also straightforward :

```
val myViewModelModule = Kodein.Module(TAG) {

    bind<MyViewModel>() with scoped<Fragment>(AndroidLifecycleScope).singleton {
        ViewModelProvider(
            this.context,
            MyViewModelFactory(instance())
        ).get(
            MyViewModel::class.java
        )
    }

    bind<AMapper>() with scoped<Fragment>(AndroidLifecycleScope).singleton {
        AMapper()
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the same MyViewModel instance in fragment B, the closest kodein being the activity ...

From my understanding, I'd need to do something like

```
class FragmentB : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodeinContext = kcontext<Fragment>(this)

    override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        extend(fragmentAKodein)
    }

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by instance()
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the fragmentAKodein.

Thanks a lot

Edit :

This is what I ended up doing :

```
class FragmentA : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    protected val parentKodein by closestKodein()

    override val kodeinContext: KodeinContext<Fragment> by lazy { kcontext(childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_containing_fragment_B) as Fragment)
    }

    override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        extend(parentKodein)
        import(myViewModelModule)
    }

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by instance()
}

val myViewModelModule = Kodein.Module(TAG) {

    bind<MyViewModel>() with scoped<BaseFragment>(AndroidLifecycleScope).singleton {
        ViewModelProvider(
            context.kodeinContext.value,
            MyViewModelFactory(
                instance()
            )
        ).get(
            MyViewModel::class.java
        )
    }

    bind<AMapper>() with scoped<Fragment>(AndroidLifecycleScope).singleton {
        AMapper()
    }
}

class FragmentB : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodeinContext: KodeinContext<Fragment> by lazy {
        kcontext(parentFragment as Fragment)
    }

    override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        extend(fragmentAKodein)
    }

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by instance()
}
```

Thanks to the ViewModelFactory, the same instance of MyViewModel is shared across all fragments.

But this is a workaround as Kodein doesn't consider the mapper to be in same scope and instantiate a new one per fragment...

Comment: Two questions: do you need to stick to kodein? Can you go with already Android arch components built in approach (sharing the same viewmodel using activity scope)?

Comment: I don't have to stick with Kodein but the MPP feature is interesting (I'm migrating to Koin if I encounter too many issues)

I've using Android arch components but I want to inject this shared ViewModel instead of calling directly the factory. 
Also, I'd need to get the master fragment from the child fragments to make it work using the ViewModelFactory which is not the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

Using custom scope solved my issue : https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/258